# Reduce minimum bounty offer for the second or later bounties on the same question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, bug, bounty

I recently offered a bounty on [my first question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116394/what-is-12-in-this-same-pattern), but it didn't receive much attention, nor had it received any answers. The option to offer/start another bounty is now gone (the link-like button now says "Question eligible for bounty since May 31"). I know that "all bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances".

**Is it** gone because I don't have enough reputation to offer another bounty (as the minimum bounty offer is 100 and I have only 83 now), or because the question has no answers to bounty (is the minimum bounty offer how much I want, or is it the previous's double)?

If it's not gone because of that (*or* if it is), this is *unfair*:

1. The question didn't get attention/the bounty wasn't worth its reason.
2. An answer posted after the first answer bountied by the same person may not be as good as the first/or may be better than the first, so the person would want to award more/less bounty than the double/500.
3. It is just so illogical.

If it's gone because I don't have 100 reputation, the minimum bounty offer should be reduced to 50. *If an answer is posted*, I **should be able to** give it how much ever bounty I want.

**Edit**: there's now [an answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/116618/80065) to it. What I want is to be able to reward a bounty of only 50 reputation (not 100) because it proves that the question isn't that hard and is answerable.

I still haven't got an actual answer to this.

Comment: Why the downvote? Why do you disagree?

Comment: *"The question didn't get attention"* is impossible to state with any accuracy unless you know it had zero views during the entire bounty period.

Answer (score 3):

From an answer to [Second bounty should be doubled the amount only if there is an awarded bounty in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188481/)

> If an initial bounty did not attract any good answers, a new bounty should be for a larger amount, to work better towards attracting answers.

and

> Doubling the required bounty is a feature partly intended to limit "bounty abuse".

These are explained more in the main-meta duplicate.

Comment: I know that "doubling the required bounty is a feature partly intended to limit 'bounty abuse'". That's not the thing in my case. Why is the link-like button gone? What about the other part of the question? Also, if a new answer is posted, I should be able to *specifically award a bounty* (as the answer exists and the question isn't that difficult).